# System.NotImplementedException error

Tags: c#

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.  I made a form that when the user clicks a button it is supposed to laod another page with information on it.  Instead of loading I get this error page:

```
The method or operation is not implemented. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Source Error: 

    public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel(string p)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 

Source File:    Line: 203
```

I'm not sure what all I would need to post here in order to give enough information for help.

Here is the code where the error might be.  I think I might have something out of place:

```
    public clsDataLayer()
    {

    }

    // This function gets the user activity from the tblPersonnel
    public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel(string Database, string strSearch)
    {
        dsPersonnel DS;
        OleDbConnection sqlConn;
        OleDbDataAdapter sqlDA;

        //create the connection string 
        sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + Database);

        string query;
        if (strSearch == "" || strSearch.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT * from tblPersonnel";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "select * from tblPersonnel where LastName = '" + strSearch + "'";
        }


        // Defines sqlDA and what each will consist of
        sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblPersonnel", sqlConn);

        // Defines DS and what each will consist of
        DS = new dsPersonnel();

        // Outputs the results from the information gathered
        sqlDA.Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);

        // Starts over for a new user
        return DS;
    }

    // This function saves the user activity
    public static void SavePersonnel(string Database, string FormAccessed)
    {
        // Defines the connection to the database
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        string strSQL;

        strSQL = "Insert into tblPersonnel (UserIP, FormAccessed) values ('" +
            GetIP4Address() + "', '" + FormAccessed + "')";

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = strSQL;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }

    public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the GetPersonnel method? The stub will by default will throw a NotImplementedException until you actually implement the method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The specific method you are calling (considering it is not a class library method) is more than likely specifically doing this:

```
 throw new NotImplementedException();
```

It's a stub right now. This is code in your solution; so on your page, your method is likely not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You or someone else might have added the `GetPersonnel()` method using Visual Studio auto code generation technique which inserts a `NotImplementedException` line in code and you have to manually remove it.

Inside your `GetPersonnel()` method, remove the `throw new NotImplementedException`... line, and implement the method completely to return some value matching the return type of the method.

Comment: I posted the code above in my original question.  You say to implement the method.  I think it is already.  If I delete the throw new NotImplementedException() statement I get a lot of other errors.  That's why I think I have something flipped around?

Comment: Well. One of the overloaded methods is not implemented which might be called while Page load, please implement it..!!

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the page you are loading does not implement the GetPersonnel method which is accessed by its code during the load process.  I think you should check the source of the page being loaded and implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the error says. You have a line of code where you're throwing a not implemented exception. Look here:

Line 201: public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel(string p) Line 202: { Line 203: throw new NotImplementedException(); Line 204: } Line 205:}

Answer (score 0):

For the beginners try below code to comment or remove that piece of code

```
   throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know what you should return just comment that piece of code

`throw new NotImplementedException();`

and replace it with

`return 0;`